# A riddle for your time (2)

Tags: riddle

> Alone I am 24th, with a friend I am 20. Another friend and I am unclean.

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> **X**

**Explanation**

Alone I am 24th

> 'X' is the 24th letter in the alphabets

with a friend I am 20

> 'X' with another 'X' gives 'XX', which is equal to 20 in roman numeral system.

Another friend and I am unclean

> I think it's referring to 'XXX', which most people consider as dirty.

Comment: A fast response yet again, good work ;)

Comment: actually I'm thinking about Gold since 24 Karat is pure, combined with other metals it can be 20 Karat haha But the last clue missed the Gold properties.